# Secure CDN content for a multi-tenant application

Tags: authentication, authorization

We have a multi-tenanted application that has sensitive content behind a secure login. We'd like to host that content on a CDN but prevent unauthorised users from accessing it.

What are the best ways to do this?

For example, we have the following resource: https://customer-a.example.com/content/video.mp4. We want this served via a CDN however you need to be logged in to customer-a.example.com to see it. How does a CDN prevent anybody from getting the URL and accessing the content?

Comment: There are a number of ways. Most CDNs now support similar machinery- signed URLs, signed cookies, Authorization headers, and others. Which to use really depends on the client delivery needs and the authentication options available. AWS Cloudfront has good documentation on their specific details: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

Answer (score -1):

This really depends on your CDN. Most would minimally check the referrer and some would support single-use or restricted URLs (e.g. only available to a certain IP, time range, etc.).

Check any hot-link prevention documentation of the CDN or ask their technical support for options.

However, for any content, somebody can always download it and reshare it, so if you want maximum protection, you'll have to use some DRM.

Comment: `you'll have to use some DRM.` which would provide no additional security and annoy the hell out of users ;-)